# Pass parameters to a directive without a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very basic directive, and the directive includes a template. In the template there is a `color` variable to set the background color of what is loaded.

```
app.directive('percentageSquare', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/charts/PercentageChart.html'
    };
});
```

Is there a way for me to set the color in my directive? I was thinking maybe something like this:

```
<percentage-square color="red"></percentage-square>
```

The template would look like this:

```
<div style="background-color: {{color}}">
    <h1>I am a cool color!</h1>
</div>
```

As I was looking all I could find was the values set in the controller (outside of the directive), is there a way I can do this by just passing a value through the HTML?

Comment: You're looking for an [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). The `scope` attribute of the directive means that you are binding some value from outside the directive. Or you can treat it as the `parameters` passed to the directive.

Check the JSFiddle working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0547gjzs/1/.

```
app.directive('percentageSquare', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            color: '@'
        }
        templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/charts/PercentageChart.html'
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<percentage-square color="red"></percentage-square>
```

Comment: In the template I have data from another scope, adding the scope seems to override the other scope...

Comment: Yes. You can bind your data from your `another scope` to this directive through `@`, `=` or `&` as well. In my opinion, a directive better interacts with others through its isolate scope. It makes this directive reusable on different pages.

Answer (score 0):

Use scope if you access color attribute of your directive.

```
app.directive('percentageSquare', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
                  color : "@"
                },
        /*templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard/charts/PercentageChart.html'*/
        template : "<div style='background-color : {{color}}'><h1>I am a cool color!</h1></div>"
    };
});
```

use same way to use templateUrl file.

here your Custom Directive Define

```
<percentage-square color="red"></percentage-square>
```